# robot framework doesn't see user defined keywords if they are in the same file as testcase

Tags: robotframework

Hi ' I'm newbie in robot framework. I try to declare keywords in the same file as testcases. But robotframework doesn't see them. I use robotframework 3.2.2 Please advice:

```
*** Settings ***
Library  SeleniumLibrary

*** Variables ***


*** Test Cases ***
User must sign in to check out
[Documentation] This is some basic info about the test
[Tags] Smoke
    Begin Web Test
    Search for Products
    Select Product from Search Results
    Add product to Cart
    Begin checkout
    End Web Test

*** Keywords ***
Begin Web Test
    Open Browser  about:blank  ie

Search for Products
    Go To   http://amazon.com
    Wait Until Page Contains  Today's Deals
    Input Text  Ferrari 458
    Click Button  xpath=//*[@id="nav-search-submit-text"]/input
    Wait Until Page Contains  results for "Ferrari 458"

Select Product from Search Results
    Click Link  xpath=//*[@id="search"]/div[1]/div[2]/div/span[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/span/div/div/div[2]/h2/a
    Wait Until Page Contains  Back to results

Add product to Cart
    Click Button  id=add-to-cart-button
    Wait Until Page Contains  Added to Cart

Begin checkout
    Click Link  Proceed to checkout (1 item)
    Wait Until Page Contains  Continue

End Web Test
    Close Browser
```

Answer (score 1):

`[Documentation]` and `[Tags]` need to be indented.

There should be at least 2 spaces between `[Documentation]` and "This is some basic info about the test"

There should also be at least 2 spaces between `[Tags]` and Smoke

```
User must sign in to check out
   [Documentation]  This is some basic info about the test
   [Tags]  Smoke
   Begin Web Test
   Search for Products
   Select Product from Search Results
   Add product to Cart
   Begin checkout
   End Web Test
```

Comment: No keyword with name 'This is some basic info about the test' found. ?

Comment: Did you copy and paste the code block I put in? It needs to be indented

Comment: Sorry I tried to type by my self. Your code fixed my issue. Thank you

Comment: no worries, I didn't make it very clear. Tried to format it better

Comment: Also I needed to install more recent version of seleniumlibrary. Because is buggy. I installed version 3.3.1 . And now even autocomplete works in Pycharm.                                             
 pip install robotframework-seleniumlibrary==3.3.1

Comment: Autocomplete is a feature of the IDE you use. It has nothing to do with robotframework problems. You could would run in newest versions of libraries.